# Sentiment Analysis R Naive Bayes in german

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I've got a problem with the naive bayes algorithm and I'm not able to find out why. I tried out an online tutorial and so in the beginning I started to create some training data. In the code below I use just very few training data, but it's the same problem.

```
pos_tweets =  rbind(
  c('Ich liebe das auto', 'positive'),
  c('Diese Aussicht ist großartig', 'positive'),
  c('toller morgen', 'positive'),
  c('ich freue mich so', 'positive'),
  c('du bist aber lieb, danke', 'positive')
)

neg_tweets = rbind(
  c('ich hasse autos', 'negative'),
  c('der blick ist horror', 'negative'),
  c('voll müde heute', 'negative'),
  c('schreckliche stille', 'negative'),
  c('er ist ein feind', 'negative')
)

test_tweets = rbind(
    c('Schöne Momente erlebt', 'positive'),
    c('zusammen macht es gleich doppelt spass', 'positive'),
    c('Yeah, toller Tag', 'positive'),
    c('Super schöne Umgebung', 'positive'),
    c('es zieht ein leichter wind auf, sehr angenehm', 'positive')
)

tweetsbind = rbind(pos_tweets, neg_tweets, test_tweets)

matrix1= create_matrix(tweetsbind[,1], language="german", 
                      removeStopwords=FALSE, removeNumbers=TRUE, 
                      stemWords=FALSE) 
mat1 = as.matrix(matrix1)
```

Now I train my model:

```
classifier1 = naiveBayes(mat1[1:10,], as.factor(tweetsbind[1:10,2]) )
```

And now I want to use it:

```
predicted = predict(classifier1, mat1[11:15,]); predicted
```

When I look into my model it look pretty good, because the negative words are marked as negative and the positive ones as positive.

But while using the model to analyse the testing data, it only outputs negative, even when the statement are obviously positive and the used word also exist in the training set.

---

My new code is:

```
# search for some twitter data
happy <- searchTwitter(":)",n = 10000, lang ='de')
happy_text <- sapply(happy, function (x) x$getText())
sad <- searchTwitter(":(",n = 10000, lang ='de')
sad_text <- sapply(sad, function (x) x$getText())

# create the matrix
tweets <- rbind(sad_text[1:2500,], happy_text[1:2500,]) # if I use more training data, I get a storage error
tweet <- as.matrix(tweets)
matrix= create_matrix(tweet[,2], language= "german", removeStopwords=FALSE, removeNumbers=TRUE,  stemWords=FALSE) 
matrixdoc = as.matrix(matrix)

# transform to factor and train the model
X <- as.data.frame(matrixdoc[1:5000,])
X$out <- as.factor(tweet[1:5000,3])
X <- as.data.frame(lapply(X, factor))
classifierstack <- naiveBayes(out ~ ., data=X)

# predict
predicted = predict(classifierstack, mat1[11:15,],type = "raw" )
```

And this is the result: everything ist negativ, even if all my inputs are very positiv (I changed them).

```
     negativ       positiv
[1,]       1 5.828223e-176
[2,]       1 4.110223e-244
[3,]       1 3.274458e-244
[4,]       1 3.534996e-176
[5,]       1  0.000000e+00
```

And if I try this:

```
> predict(classifierstack, "zeigt", type = "raw" )
     negativ positiv
[1,]     0.5     0.5
```

-> it always outputs 0.5 0.5 and is finally always negativ :/

Comment: Are you using the `naiveBayes` from the `e1071` package?

Comment: Yes, I am using the e1071 package

Comment: Your update isn't reproducible, so can't see what goes wrong with your data. What is `testS`? Did you get the same results I did below on your original data/question?

Comment: Yes testS were only some testdata in a csv, but in this case I tested the old data from mat1[11:15,]. I think there is a problem with the claffified model because negaiv is always 1 and positiv much lower, so consequently it returns always negativ, but how can I change this. I updated the code (delted the testS) and now it should be reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lacking training data. If I run your code I get

```
> predicted = predict(classifier1, mat1[11:15,]); predicted
[1] negative negative negative positive negative
Levels: negative positive
```

So only the first two elements are wrong - the last three should indeed be negative, postive and negative. If we look at the classifier information for the words found in, say, *feinde sind doof* we find

```
                             feinde
as.factor(tweetsbind[1:10, 2]) [,1] [,2]
                      negative    0    0
                      positive    0    0

                              sind
as.factor(tweetsbind[1:10, 2]) [,1] [,2]
                      negative    0    0
                      positive    0    0

                              doof
as.factor(tweetsbind[1:10, 2]) [,1] [,2]
                      negative    0    0
                      positive    0    0
```

so there really is no information to classify and it defaults to the first level category, `negative`. Try to feed it more information where there is an overlap between the words you want to predict and it should work.

---

**Update** If you run

```
> predicted = predict(classifier1, mat1[11:15,], type="raw"); predicted
         negative     positive
[1,] 9.999959e-01 4.093637e-06
[2,] 7.329224e-01 2.670776e-01
[3,] 1.000000e+00 4.598781e-11
[4,] 9.898881e-05 9.999010e-01
[5,] 1.000000e+00 1.608783e-16
```

then you can see the individual probabilities. The "problem" with your fit is that the input is read as being numeric (and not as binary factors) so you will not see conditional probabilities that (row-wise) add up to one. As per the man page for `naiveBayes` you get Gaussian means and sds. You can get the conditional probabilities like this:

```
X <- as.data.frame(mat1[1:10,])
X$out <- as.factor(tweetsbind[1:10,2])
X <- as.data.frame(lapply(X, factor))
naiveBayes(out ~ ., data=X)
```

This will give you

```
          hab
Y          0
  negative 1
  positive 1
          dich
Y          0
  negative 1
  positive 1
          lieb
Y            0   1
  negative 1.0 0.0
  positive 0.8 0.2
```

Those are the P(lieb|positive) probabilities and you need to you Bayes formula to invert the probabilities.

Google "zero problem" and "naive bayes" to get directions for making slight improvements when the words aren't present in both training and test parts (see the `laplace` argument).

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, it already helped me a lot! 
The case you explained I understand :) but if you look at the sentence "c('hab dich lieb', 'positive') then normally "lieb" should be positive because the training set includes the sentence: c('du bist aber lieb, danke', 'positive'). So I do not understand why the algorithm returns that this sentence is negative?


                              lieb
as.factor(tweetsbind[1:10, 2]) [,1]      [,2]
                      negative  0.0 0.0000000
                      positive  0.2 0.4472136

Comment: Yeah but you have two words that don't improve the probability. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thank you, but if I use your code I only get negative results (and I even tried it out with 5000 training data tweets.

> predicted
     negativ       positiv
[1,]       1 2.610912e-223
[2,]       1 1.147911e-223
[3,]       1 2.610912e-223
[4,]       1 2.610912e-223
[5,]       1 8.703038e-224

Comment: Please update your question so we can see exactly what you did. It will be easier to follow